# Send a byte array using HTTP Post without using MultipartEntity

Tags: android

I need to post byte array to a webservice, but it is not supporting Multipart form. So, I searched to find some other way. I found this code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(address);
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1", "value1"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key2", "value2"));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

But it will allow me to send strings only, and I want to send byte arrays. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Post it as a string?

```
byte[] array = new byte[n];
array[0] = ..
array[n] = ..

String dataToSend = "";
For(int i = 0; i < array.length -1; i++){
dataToSend += (char) array[0];
}

// your post code here
...
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1", dataToSend));
```